# Image not replacing with jQuery [Elementor]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

(First time posting on stack overflow, not sure if this format is correct)

Does anyone have any idea on how to change an elementor image with jQuery on hover?

So far I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.yellow-button').on({
     'mouseenter': function(){
         $('#change-image img').attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/random.jpg");
     }
 });
});
```

I tested the selector with show()/hide() and it seems to work (it appears and disappears). Here's the code for it:

```
$('.yellow-button').on({
     'mouseenter': function(){
         $('#change-image img').hide();
```

Since it's working, I think the main issue is the attr() bit here:

```
$('#change-image img').attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/random.jpg")
```

So far, for both variables inside attr, I tried random combinations of the full domain link, ' and " but none seem to work.

Got any clues on what to do? Thanks!

I'm not sure if this helps, but here's the HTML for the image bit:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-383b78f elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="383b78f" data-element_type="widget" id="change-image" data-widget_type="image.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <div class="elementor-image">
                                                <img width="900" height="300" src="http://somewebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/lock-4.png" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="random" loading="lazy" srcset="http://somewebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/lock-4.png 900w, http://somewebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/lock-4-300x100.png 300w, http://somewebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/lock-4-768x256.png 768w" sizes="(max-width: 900px) 100vw, 900px" />                                                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using your browser devtools to see if the src attributes is actually updating in the Dom?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: *"That's because I tested the selector with show()/hide() and the image did disappear/reappear when I hover over the 'yellow button'."* can you share the code of that test? (please ensure it actually works)

Comment: @badsyntax I'm not super familiar with devtools (or jQuery itself), but the src attribute inside the img element is updating. I have srcset inside but that's not updating. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @KevinB I've updated that in the comments and confirm it still works. Thanks

Comment: @WilsonLiu yes that's the problem, you also need to update the srcSet attribute

Comment: @badsyntax Thanks, I just removed it and it seems to work. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

To everyone using elementor, here's the answer:

```
$('.buttonClassName').on({
     'mouseenter': function(){
         $('#imageIDName img').attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/random.jpg").removeAttr("srcset");
     }
 });
});
```

The main difference compared to guided/original answers is as follows:

- In the selector, added img after the #imageIDName.
- Removed 'srcset' attribute, I guess it was clashing with 'src' so the new image wasn't rendering.

I'm not sure how this would look in responsive, because I only needed this for desktop.